# Due to the probabilistic nature of particles, is it possible for a photon to arrive at a location slightly earlier than the speed of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, probability

Due to particles not having a specific location in space unless it is observed (i.e. it is a probability wave), would this mean that a photon can appear slightly ahead of where the speed of light shows that it should be (Such as 299,792,460 meters away from a source instead of 299,792,458 after one second). The principle of a photon not having a specific location, but rather a superposition of probable locations, as shown by the double slit experiment, it stands to reason that this applies to its location in the direction of relative motion. I feel like I am missing something that makes this line of thinking incorrect, thus why I am posting this question. Is this idea flawed, or is a photon's location (and thus the time at which it arrives a given location) in its direction of relative motion uncertain and thus probabilistic?

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky, because you have to ask yourself how you know whether it actually traveled faster than light or not.  The only way to be sure is to measure its position at both the beginning and the end.  And there are further complications.  When relativity is taken into account, you need to think about the reference frame of the measurement and other finicky details.  Another complication is that there usually isn't a great way of measuring a photon without destroying it, and you need to do two measurements.

Let's ignore the complications and assume that you can measure it at both the beginning and end of its path, and assume that we are using the standard model of particle physics.

In this case, the answer to your question is no.  When you measure it at the beginning, then for a brief moment, the photon's position *is* well-defined.  After that, the quantum field of the photon will "spread out" again, but it does so at the speed of light.  So there is no way to measure it at the end and observe it traveling faster than the speed of light.

There are a variety of other complicated concepts that could play a role in slightly altered scenarios, such as virtual particles, but they are not relevant here.

Occasionally over the years, someone makes a measurement that seems to indicate faster-than-light travel.  One such incident occurred a couple of years ago when a particle physics experiment asked for help saying, "We're observing something that looks like faster-than-light travel.  Can someone come and double-check what we're doing?"  In every case it has been found not to be true.  (In that particular case I think it had something to do with the electronics equipment they were using.)

Comment: One thing that bothers me is that, since a photon can have a well-defined momentum, its location probability wave should not be capable of being well-defined enough to be specifically before C. If one were to measure the momentum of a photon, and then measure the position (by this, I mean set a detector at a specific location that measures when the photon is detected), could it be slightly ahead of C? Moreover, if you know when and where the photon was emitted (a laser that you set, perhaps?), is the first measurement necessary?

Comment: Also, If the wave does spread like you said, in such a way that isn't inherently C (which is the impression that I got from your answer), why can't it be slightly ahead of C? This would limit its possible locations in a way that contradicts the uncertainty principle if you know its momentum. It also seems can appear slightly behind C (or else it would have a defined position in the direction of relative motion), so what is stopping it from appearing/being detected slightly ahead of expectation due to its probabilistic nature?

Comment: @Sciencemaster This is complicated, and it's hard to adequately resolve your questions without learning the math of quantum mechanics.  But let me try to answer your first question.  If you measure the momentum and then you measure the position, *how would you even know* if it is "slightly ahead of $c$"?  Position and momentum are "incompatible measurements" in quantum mechanics, which means that if you know one, you don't know the other.  To say how far it has traveled, you would have to measure the position at the beginning and end.

Comment: Your second idea, "if you know when and where the photon was emitted," is also a good idea, but unfortunately this when and where is not well-defined in quantum mechanics.  It is probabilistic.  And in a laser, you have an enormous number of photons, and the individual emission time for each one is not well-defined (and would be impossible to measure even if it were).

Comment: Finally, I think that I gave an incorrect impression, because I didn't say that the wave spreads in a way that "isn't inherently" at the speed of light.  The wave function *does* spread at $c$.  All of the standard theories of quantum field theory are *local*, which means that all interactions happen no faster than $c$.

Comment: The argument I gave is as follows.  If you didn't measure its position at the beginning and end, then you don't know how much the wave function had already spread out at the very beginning before you tried to measure the speed, so you can't really say you are measuring the speed.  And if you *do* measure it at the beginning and end, then you can measure the speed, but the position is completely localized at the beginning, so when it spreads out, it will spread out at $c$ and you will never observe a speed greater than $c$.

Comment: If you had asked about momentum rather than energy, and asked whether it is always true that $E=pc$ for photons, then the case of virtual particles would become important enough for a discussion.  But in this case it is not.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your answer and providing more information. First off, when I said what if you measured the momentum and then position of a photon, I was thinking along the lines of, If you measure a photon's momentum, it cannot have a defined position, and thus cannot be exactly where it would be moving exactly at C (such as 299,792,460 meters away after 1 second), as opposed to measuring them simultaneously, which, as you said, would be impossible, as measuring momentum would collapse the wave function of a photon's position.

Comment: Second, when I said that you said that a photon's probability wave doesn't inherently spread at C, I had gotten the impression that it could spread at a rate that is less than C, in which case, what would be stopping it from being ahead of C if its position was not well-defined enough. Going back, however, I definitely misinterpreted your answer, as I was focusing on how you said the wave function "spread" out over time in the third paragraph in your original answer. I must have missed the part where you said that it spread at C.

Comment: Finally, I just don't understand how a photon can have a well-defined momentum momentum, yet still move out in any number of directions at exactly C, which inherently means that the position must be well-defined to some degree at the same time. This goes against the uncertainty principle and the entire concept of a probability wave. What am I missing here? Is it virtual particles (do they make momentum less defined to the point that it balances out the photons being at a well-defined distance away from a source at any time (exactly C away))?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Your question about having a well-defined momentum but not a well-defined direction is based on a misunderstanding.  Imagine that you can perform measurements with perfect accuracy. If you measure the photon's *momentum*, then afterwards it will be in a well-defined momentum state, which always has a well-defined direction. For example, if you make a measurement that $\vec{p}=(1, 0, 0)$ in some units, then if you measure its direction again a few seconds later, you will always find it moving to the right along the x-axis. But you might not know exactly where it is.

Comment: On the other hand, if you measure the photon's *position*, then afterward you will have no idea which direction it is moving, which is perfectly consistent with the momentum being undefined. In this case the wavefunction really does spread out in all directions at once at speed $c$. Does this answer your question? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I do believe that you misunderstood the question, although this is very interesting. I don't think that I said anything about the direction of a particle. If I did, I did not mean to, or it was not the main point. What I am asking is if a photon/other particle can have a well defined momentum, does this mean that its position is not well defined enough to be exactly where it would be if it moved at exactly C? What I mean by this, if I put a photon detector 299,792,460 meters away from a source of light, and fired off some photons, would some arrive slightly before/after one second?

Comment: This would be as opposed to arriving exactly one second after being fired off, as one would expect from a particle moving at C.

Comment: @Sciencemaster The whole point of my answer is that it is much more complicated than that.  First of all, the comment about the direction has to do with the incompatibility of measuring position and momentum, which was important to a previous question of yours.  Second, let's consider the scenario you are proposing.  You put a photon position measurement apparatus one light second away from a light source and then ask whether the arrival time is always one second.  The biggest question here is: How do you know what time the light was emitted?  ...

Comment: ... (I could also ask how you know that this photon came from the same light source and other annoying questions, but I won't go there.)  Without answering that question, you cannot say whether the photon was traveling faster than $c$ or not.  And in order to answer that question, you have to put some sort of detector at the light source, and then you are in exactly the same situation that I described in my original answer.  ...

Comment: ... A proper understanding of quantum mechanics will show that, in general, we expect the photon to be in a superposition of different positions, different times of emission, different momenta, and so forth when it is emitted.  In order to make a concrete connection to classical concepts like well-defined *position*, *speed*, *time*, *momentum*, *energy*, etc., you have to perform measurements.  And this is the part that you keep leaving out of your explanation.  ...

Comment: ... (How to interpret this is a fairly deep subject, and after you learn the standard textbook "Copenhagen" interpretation of quantum mechanics, you can start learning about other [interpretations of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) to start making sense of this.  Personally I'm an advocate of the decoherence/many minds interpretation, but that's a digression that I can't fit into a comment.)  ...

Comment: ... Anyway, let me restate the conclusion of my original answer.  If you want to think about classical concepts like speed that rely on having a well-defined position, which is what your original question sounds like, then you have to perform two measurements.  If you want to just talk about the quantum wavefunction, with no reference to classical observables, then it propagates at exactly $c$.  You have to pick one of these two questions, and either way you have your answer.

Comment: First off, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. They are helpful to my understanding of quantum mechanics. I understand what you are saying about having to measure the photon (or other particle) twice, and it is making sense to me now. It is always in a superposition of states, and speed can only be defined as the difference in locations between two times *which requires two measurements to make well-defined*. This is what I got out of this, is this correct? However, at the end of your answer, you said "the quantum wavefunction,...propagates at exactly c."...

Comment: ...I simply do not understand how the wavefunction propogates at C if its position/momentum are not inherently well defined, to the point where the fact that it moves at C would make at least the position of a photon somewhat well defined. Does the momentum simply not become well-defined at all while the position (of the wave function) remains somewhat well defined after emission? This seems to be the case (that the wave itself moves at C while neither the momentum nor position change in terms of how well defined they are.

Comment: (this would explain why the position wave function itself would not stray from C at any given point). Finally, if some other particle (i.e. not massless (take an electron or proton, for example)) were to have its momentum measured (which should be possible without destroying the particle), would its position also be less well defined to the point where it could appear outside of its own "light cone" (ahead of where it would be traveling at C after a given amount of time)?

Comment: Also, why would measuring a photon destroy it? Being that photons have/are energy, wouldn't this violate conservation of energy by "destroying matter" (or is the energy given off as thermal energy or something similar)?

Comment: Some brief answers: 1. The standard interpretation of quantum mechanics (the [Copenhagen interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation)) is as follows.  When you are not making a measurement, then the wavefunction evolves according to the Schrödinger equation (or its relativistic extensions; in this case, QED).  When you are making a measurement, the wavefunction collapses, and this is basically the only time that comparisons to classical mechanics (where the particle has a well-defined position, momentum, etc.) even make sense.

Comment: There is a lot of subtlety here that can't fit into a stackoverflow comment.  However, the point is that we can talk about the time-evolution of the wavefunction, which happens at exactly $c$, between the measurements, but we can only talk about position/momentum/etc. when we make measurements.  The classical ideas you have about reality simply don't apply when you are not making a measurement.  More on this later.

Comment: 2. All of my comments in part (1) apply to massive particles as well.

Comment: 3. Measuring a photon doesn't destroy its energy.  It is just no longer a photon any more.  For example, if a photon hits an electron, the photon ceases to exist, but the electron gets the energy.  (This is like anything else in nature.  If you burn a stick, it is no longer a stick, but the mass/energy is left over in the form of heat, smoke, and ashes.)  Generally the way that we measure photons is by letting them hit something else and then we detect the energy that came from the photon.  If they had mass or charge, there would probably be other ways to detect them.

Comment: 4. If you really want to understand this, it will take a lot of time and effort.  (a) Learn enough math to take a basic quantum mechanics course (e.g., one with Griffiths's textbook).  (b) Learn this material well enough to understand the Copenhagen interpretation.  (c) When you are dissatisfied with the Copenhagen interpretation (which you almost certainly will be) then you can try to learn ideas about the underlying mechanisms involved, such as decoherence, and read about other [interpretations of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics).

Comment: If this course of action is not possible, then you will probably not be satisfied with any explanation, because QM is a deep subject that requires a lot of thought, and it cannot really properly be understood without a mathematical formulation.  But the best attempt that I have seen to explain quantum mechanics without any math at all is probably Feynman's book [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED:_The_Strange_Theory_of_Light_and_Matter), so that is an alternative that you could start with.  There are probably other recommendations elsewhere on this site as well.

Comment: that does make sense. I have been studying physics in college in order to understand this stuff (funnily enough, I wasn't even in college when I asked this question over a year ago). I really do want to understand this stuff. However, there is a clarification that I would like to make that you might be able to answer. Take a photon that has just had its position measured. It's momentum is now more uncertain. What bearing does a photon's momentum have on its motion (i.e. does photon momentum affect direction of motion)? With massive particles, at least, this momentum uncertainty...

Comment: ...causes the wavefunction to spread in position space, including in its direction of relative motion, with the 'front end' of the wavefunction moving faster through space than the center (average value). I was wondering if this is true of photons as well. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Sciencemaster Since you're in college and studying some physics now, I'll give a slightly more technical answer.  If we are talking about non-relativistic quantum mechanics, and we measure the position of a particle at $x=0$, then its wavefunction collapses to $\delta(x)$ (a spike at $x=0$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function).  In momentum space, this corresponds to a constant function, which basically means that the momentum could be literally *anything* with equal probabiity.  So there is no longer a "front end" of its motion or anything like that; it has no preferred direction.

Comment: But since your original question has to do with the speed of light, I should probably mention that if we take an appropriate *relativistic* version of quantum mechanics, such as quantum electrodynamics, then the situation is slightly more complicated.  You can basically say that if you measure the position at a given time, then the quantum field (in position space) will spread out according to the Green's function or two-point correlation function of photons in QED.  It will take you a few years to get to the point where this means anything to you, but the critical observation is that even...

Comment: ...in this case, then there is no "preferred" direction.  Basically, by measuring the position, you destroy all information about the direction that the photon was previously traveling.

Comment: I should clarify one more thing.  The preceding discussion applies to a "perfect" measurement of precision, which of course does not exist in reality.  This is all assuming that we can measure the precision of a photon with infinite precision (and without destroying it either!).  In reality, if you measure it to a given precision, then there is still some momentum information left.  This works at all the different levels of explanation (the simple Heisenberg principle, nonrelativistic QM, or quantum field theory).    If this seems bizarre or like cheating, then someday you will have to...

Comment: ...learn more about the interpretations of quantum mechanics and about decoherence, as I suggested above, but it will take a while to get there.


I haven't tried to work out the details, but for a finite measurement, here is what I *suspect* you would find to be true in a typical case.  Suppose that the photon is in a [wavepacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet) with a given position and momentum.  You measure the position with uncertainty $\sigma_x$ and find it to be 0...

Comment: ...From $\sigma_x$ and the uncertainty principle, you can calculate $\sigma_p$, the uncertainty in the momentum afterwards.  I think that the momentum distribution of the photon will typically look like a normal distribution centered around the original momentum of the wavepacket but with an uncertainty of $\sigma_p$.

Comment: This does make some sense to me. However, it doesn't seem to *quite* address the issue at hand. I was never talking about a perfect observation, just one that creates some non-trivial uncertainty in momentum. In my opinion, since the perfect measurement scenario isn't physically realizable, there is no point in arguing about it. However, if there is some bearing of photon momentum on its relative velocity, some uncertainty in momentum would create some variation in its velocity (and thus not some exact value C), correct? That's my line of thinking, at least.

Comment: @Sciencemaster Oh, now I understand what you were asking.  I thought your main concern was about the direction of the photon, not its speed.  For speed, the answer is going to disappoint you, but there isn't a nice relationship between speed and momentum for photons.  The classical equation $p=mv$ isn't true for photons.  In the case of photons, the relevant equation is $p=E/c$, where $E$ is the energy of the photon (which is proportional to the frequency of the photon).  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation)...

Comment: ...for some more background on the relativistic relationship between energy and momentum.  Basically, uncertainty in momentum for photons doesn't translate to uncertainty in speed.  This is a direct consequence of the fact that photons do not have mass.

Comment: Well, that does make sense, all things considered. So, basically, massless objects don't have uncertain speed and always move at precisely C, right? However, my initial question wasn't specifically about uncertainty in momentum; it was about uncertainty in position. Essentially, if the photon has uncertainty in position, it cannot have one specific position. As such, after it is emitted, it could be detected within a range of multiple positions. As such, it could--for instance--be at 299,792,460 meters away from the emitter instead of C, 299,792,458 after one second, could it not?

Comment: Or is this resolved by the photon's position values in its wave function not spreading out due to its lack of uncertainty in--and thus lack of superposition of--velocities?

Comment: @Sciencemaster Yes, I think that at this point we have come full circle and you can start to look at my original answer, particularly the paragraph that contains this sentence: 'After that, the quantum field of the photon will "spread out" again, but it does so at the speed of light.'  This will make sense after you learn some quantum field theory.  (This is typically in graduate school but could be done as an undergraduate if you are ambitious.)

Comment: Alright. How can the position of the photon spread (and thus the difference between the lowest possible value and highest possible value increases) without some of these values (i.e. highest or lowest possible position value) changing at a different rate than C?

Comment: @Sciencemaster Here is a simple example. Suppose the world is one-dimensional. At $t=0$ you know the photon is at $x=0$. Then I could say that there is a probability $p(x, t)$ that you will find the photon at position $x$ at time $t$ which is given by $p(x)=\Theta(|x|-ct)$. Here, $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function (i.e., $\Theta(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$ and $\Theta(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$). Please note that this is *not* the correct expression for a photon. It is an example to show how the photon can "spread out" even though it is impossible to find it moving at a speed faster than $c$.

Comment: (If you want the actual expression for a photon, search for "photon propagator" or "photon Green's function" or "photon two-point correlation function" for quantum electrodynamics.  I believe that in natural units in momentum space, it is something like $\frac{g_{\mu \nu}}{p^2 + i \epsilon}$, where $g$ is the metric tensor, $p$ is the four-momentum of the photon, and $\epsilon$ is the polarization of the photon.  But once again you will have to wait to learn field theory for this fuller answer to make sense.)

Comment: Sorry, there are some obvious errors in my example two comments above.  The expression should be something like $p(x,t) = \frac{1}{2ct} \Theta(ct - |x|)$.  But you get the basic idea.  Of course, this describes a particle which moves either slower than light or at the speed of light.  One that moves exactly at the speed of light, like an on-shell (non-"virtual") photon, would be more like $p(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} \delta(x-ct) + \frac{1}{2} \delta(x+ct)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.